# Path from 0 to Boundary of unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology

Working in $\mathbb{C}$, $D$ is the unit disk, $S$ is a simply connected open subset of $D$ not containing $0$. Is there a path from $0$ to the boundary of $D$ that is contained within $D\setminus S$?

This statement has been used in a proof of the Riemann mapping theorem that I have been reading, but I find it very non trivial.